# Problem with importing image using url function This relative module was not found

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to import an image into my page, but every time get an error:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ../video/background.gif in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=fae5bece&lang=scss
```

Here is the structure of the project:

[image]

My scss file is imported into `Home.vue` and url path looks like:

`background-image: url('../video/background.gif');`

When I am using that like WebStorm tells that everything is ok, but I get error, as you can see, I tried just put this file in folder and make url look like:

`background-image: url('background.gif');`

And it works, but WebStorm tells, that `Cannot resolve file 'background.gif'`. So, what's the problem and how can I import files correctly?

Comment: you need to do like this `background-image: url('./background.gif');` by doing `background-image: url('background.gif');` which you did, it will search the parent directory for the file.

Comment: It's not about this. I want to make `url()` function get data from `src/assets/video` folder, because it has no sense to put everything in one folder

Comment: You are import **background-gif** in `_header.scss`??

Comment: Yeah, that's true